# Facebook Like Box Widget

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, widget, fluid-layout

I've done a lot of research, the answers given through StackOveflow have made complete sense, but do not work. I've tried giving the elements a style of width:100%;, but to no avail, there is still overflow that prevents the Widget to be responsive. It looks great on a mobile device, but that is because it has been optimized for that viewport. Any advice on geting the Facebook Like Box Widget from Facebook for wordpress to be responsive and fit it's parent container?

What to write and where to write it.

http://www.seattleimpactfcshop.com

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is currently alleviating the pain, but still doesn't look that great.

.fb-comments, .fb-comments iframe[style], .fb-like-box, .fb-like-box iframe[style]{width:100% !important;}
.fb-comments span, .fb-comments iframe span[style], .fb-like-box span, .fb-like-box iframe     span[style]{width: 100% !important;}

I know the width of my sidebar area doesn't help, but it's got to be able to look "nicer."

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. and I know it requires a lot of javascript fiddling to get that right. I solved the problem by output-ing two widgets at the same time like:

```
class="fb-like" data-share="true" data-width="500" data-show-faces="false"
```

and:

```
class="fb-like" data-share="true" data-width="320" data-show-faces="false"
```

Then toggle the display block and `display:none` for each of these in mobile and desktop layouts.